# Type '(String, AnyObject)' has no subscript members in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this line to get data

```
 let productDict  = arrProductCart[sender.tag] as! [String: AnyObject]
```

and I want to filter data from dictionary so i am using this code

```
let filteredSubitems = productDict.filter{
        $0["groupid"] as!String != "1"
    }
```

it is giving me error **Type '(String, AnyObject)' has no subscript members**

do i need to convert [String: AnyObject] to  [String: String]?
what to do.

Comment: `[String: AnyObject]` this means dictionary ... not array and dictionary doesn't have subscript member

Comment: Filter, Map, Reduce are used on Array, Set (In general the datastructure which can be enumerated). Hence the error.

Comment: @KrutarthPatel Take care about those cases when `groupId` value is not a String. Don't use forced unwrapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you want to filter `arrProductCard` array instead of `productDict`, which doesn't make sense. Try this:

```
let filteredProducts = arrProductCard.filter{
    guard let groupId = $0["groupid"] as? String else { return false }
    return groupId != "1"
}
```

You should avoid forced unwrapping whenever you can. Note that your code inside filter closure will crash if there is no `groupid` value in the dictionary or if it is not a string.

**Edit:**

If you're using `NSMutableArray` for some reason, you can just filter it with a predicate:

```
let mutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: [["groupid": "1"], ["groupid": "2"]])    
let groupIdPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "groupid != %@", "1")
mutableArray.filter(using: groupIdPredicate)
```

However, I would strongly recommend to use Swift native collections.

Comment: Gratefulness for nice explanation

Comment: one question. data is filtered.but in arrProductCard data is still there.can it not be removed/

Comment: Just set the result in the same variable: `arrProductCard = arrProductCard.filter {...}`

Comment: i use nsmutuablearray so getting error  Cannot assign value of type '[Element]' to type 'NSMutableArray'

Comment: let groupIdPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "NewGroupID != %@", "1")
            arrProductCart.filterUsingPredicate(groupIdPredicate)

Comment: @KrutarthPatel I don't know why you changed "groupid" key to "NewGroupID"

Comment: becuase in my project it is NewGroupID.so